# Changing field names in edmx file in a smart way

Tags: entity-framework

I've just noticed how terribly tough Entity Framework makes simple task of changing name of some field in some table in the model. There are following difficulties. Renaming (or changing type) of field using GUI:

- doesn't change the mapping
- doesn't rename names in generated models, but regenerates them

So after renaming a field we need to manually update edmx's xml and deal with all references to old name of the generated POCO in all places of our project.

Is there any way to do it smarter? Are there any tools for it?

(I'm using EF 4)

Comment: Well, how would EF know you *renamed* a field? You may as well have deleted a field and added a new one. If you rename two or more fields in one table it's even impossible for EF to match old and new names.

Comment: Visual Studio can refactor code in whole project if we click rename, so I don't know what's unusual in such a feature.

Comment: OK, so you're talking about changing *properties* (I thought database fields) in the edmx designer (GUI can be anything). Then I don't know what you mean by *doesn't change the mapping*. If you rename a property, why should the mapping change?